# How do I pass an NSIndexPath through a button within a cell to another ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uitableview

I have a button in every cell of a table.  When the button is pressed it gets the NSIndexPath of the cell that button is in.  The button is a segue to another view controller.  How do I get that NSIndexPath into the new viewcontroller? If I use override func prepareforSegue I can't access the variable to pass it through because it is within the button function.  I could probably make the variable accessible to the TableViewCell class, but I don't know how to declare an empty NSIndexPath or if you can do that, and also if it can be done it might lead to other problems.  Or is that the best way to do it?

Comment: why do you want NSIndexPath in different view controllers? it smells like wrong design.

Comment: I have table with posts for a social network and have a segue when I click the comment button, to load all comments for that post in the next view controller.  Do you know the proper way?  I was going to use the index path to get the comments from the table datasource, that's the only way that I know of.

Comment: The pattern you implement is master-detail. I don't know your implementation of data source, may be it's safe in your case. so you pass indexpath to nested controller to pick some object from array. what if the contents of array is changed while user is learning master screen? it's better to pass some PostId to comments screen and then populate comments array based on PostID parameter.

Comment: Could you possibly point me in the direction of where you learned "patterns" such as master-detail?  You seem to have a really good knowledge of how everything works and that's what I'm trying to get so I can get an IOS developer job.  Sorry if it's out of context I just don't know where to learn this stuff.  Six years in college and never even touched on this stuff, or mobile development for that matter.

Comment: I'm trying to do it that way because I see what you mean, it could lead to getting the wrong post's comments.  I can't seem to get the post ID though because I have to know which post is being clicked and the only way I can think of doing that is with the index path.  How else would it know which cell's button is being pressed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can declare the variable accessible from everywhere like this:

`var selectedIndexPath: NSIndexPath?`

Comment: Yup I didn't know I could do this I thought I had to give it a value upon declaration.  Still learning the syntax.  Also I wasn't sure if this was the proper way to do it, but if no one else replies I'll just do it this way.